# How do I get the time zone id from a time zone

Tags: java, android, timezone

I want the country name(time zone id) based on time zone like

```
america/new_york
```

My current code is

```
String time_zone = TimeZone.getDefault().getDisplayName(false, TimeZone.SHORT);
```

This returns GMT-05:00

Comment: Country name != Time zone ID. USA has I think 10 time zones (including all the overseas territories), but just one name. It's fine to want to use the time zone id; just don't treat it as if it is the country's name.

Comment: Ok, I understood

Comment: The canonical time zone names do not contain a country.  The format is `Area/Locality`.  In most cases, "area" is a *continent* or an *ocean*.  For example, `America/Sao_Paulo` is in *Brazil*, which is in South America, and Hawaii is `Pacific/Honolulu`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can get country name using this

```
TimeZone.getDefault().getID()
```

Answer (score 3):

The country is not part of the time zone data.

For instance, it's not reliably encoded in the ID, as in `Africa/Abidjan` or `America/Cancun`.

The only way you can do this is with an explicit lookup table mapping time zone id to country.

Comment: I am using time zone id as country,

Comment: So... Your question is not "how do I get the country", but "how do I get the time zone id from a time zone"? That's quite a big difference.